# Как найти k-ый уровень дерева?

Tags: c, алгоритм

Дерево задается списком дуг. Первый массив - это начало дуги, второй массив - конец дуги.

```
A(2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6,  9,  1)
B(3, 5, 6, 9, 4, 1, 10, 15, 22)
```

Как найти к-ый уровень дерева? Корень = 2 нулевой уровень. Язык С.

Comment: @Dread, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Человек может алгоритм хотел узнать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью поиска в ширину, с остановкой после нужного нам уровня. Напишу код на C++, так будет понятен сам алгоритм:

```
vector<int> findLevel(Node* root, int targetLevel) {
    queue<pair<Node*, int>> Q;
    Q.push(make_pair(root, 0));
    vector<int> result;
    while (!Q.empty()) {
        Node* curNode = Q.top().first;
        int curLevel = Q.top().second;
        Q.pop();
        if (curLevel > targetLevel) {
            break;
        }
        if (curLevel == targetLevel) {
            result.push_back(curNode->value);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < curNode->childrenNumber(); ++i) {
            Q.push(make_pair(curNode->child(i), curLevel + 1));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```